# How do I break elements for <TR> in a nested foreach?

Tags: php

My goal is to break the array of currencies per reward type as shown in the image:

[image]

However, I'm getting this output instead (it lists all currency rewards of each deck type per TR line):
[image]

And my current code is this (I apologize for the messy code):

```
// Sample array values
$choiceVal = "2, 3, 4";
$randomVal = "3, 4, 5";
$moneyVal = "0 | 20, 2 | 25, 3 | 30";
$tcgCurr = "charm points.png, lollipop.png";

// Run array of rewards
$choiceDeck = explode(", ", $choiceVal);
$randomDeck = explode(", ", $randomVal);
$moneyDeck = explode(", ", $moneyVal);

// Explode currency bombs
foreach( $moneyDeck as $ext => $value )
{
    $curValue = explode(' | ', $moneyDeck[$ext]);
    $curName = explode(', ', $tcgCurr);

    foreach( $curValue as $key => $value )
    {
        $tn = substr_replace($curName[$key],"",-4);
        if( $curValue[$key] > 1 )
        {
            $var = substr($tn, -1);
            if( $var == "y" )
            {
                $tn = substr_replace($tn,"ies",-1);
            }
            else if( $var == "o" )
            {
                $tn = substr_replace($tn,"oes",-1);
            }
            else
            {
                $tn = $tn.'s';
            }
        }

        else
        {
            $tn = $tn;
        }

        if( $curValue[$key] == 0 ) {}
        else
        {
            $arrayCur[] = $curValue[$key].' '.$tn.', ';
        }
    }
}
// Fix all bombs after explosions
$arrayCur = implode(" ", $arrayCur);
$arrayCur = substr_replace($arrayCur,"",-2);

// Display table of rewards
echo '<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" width="40%" align="center">Mastery</th>
        <th scope="row" width="60%" align="center">Rewards</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>';

foreach( $randomDeck as $disp => $value )
{
    // Add tr lines for each deck mastery type
    if( $disp == 0 ) { $mast = 'Regular'; }
    elseif( $disp == 1 ) { $mast = 'Special'; }
    elseif( $disp == 2 ) { $mast = 'Rare'; }
            
    echo '<tr>
        <td align="center">'.$mast.' Decks</td>
        <td align="center">'.$choiceDeck[$disp].' choice, '.$randomDeck[$disp].' random, '.$arrayCur.'</td>
    </tr>';
}

echo '</tbody>
</table>';
```

The problem I was having was the `$arrayCur`, where it was supposed to break on new  lines as follows: 20 lollipops  2 charm points, 25 lollipops  3 charm points, 30 lollipops. But they were all being listed on each  line as shown in the image above.

Any work-around or easy way and help to achieve this goal is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The issue obviously is the content of the variable `$arrayCur`. It does not contain what you probably think.

Comment: @arkascha Hello~! Yes. I'm well aware that it's the `$arrayCur` that causes the issue. It is what I need help in breaking. Thank you :)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this even related to `<tr>` in any case? The generated table does not look like you are facing any markup issue

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase! I'm really not good at explaining, that's why I've put up an image of desired output VS actual output. The problem I was having was the `$arrayCur`, where it was supposed to break on new <TR> lines as follows: 20 lollipops <new TR line> 2 charm points, 25 lollipops <new TR line> 3 charm points, 30 lollipops. But they were all being listed on each <TR> lines. I was able to obtain this goal just a while ago, many thanks tho. ^_^

Comment: Feel free to add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure this one out after taking a break for a couple of days. The initial code has a bunch of `foreach` so I've tried to make a work-around by merging the currency foreach and the TR lines foreach instead. :)

```
// Sample array values
$choiceVal = "2, 3, 4";
$randomVal = "3, 4, 5";
$moneyVal = "0 | 20, 2 | 25, 3 | 30";
$tcgCurr = "charm points.png, lollipop.png";

// Run array of rewards
$choiceDeck = explode(", ", $choiceVal);
$randomDeck = explode(", ", $randomVal);
$moneyDeck = explode(", ", $moneyVal);

echo '<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" width="40%" align="center">Mastery</th>
        <th scope="row" width="60%" align="center">Rewards</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>';

    foreach( $moneyDeck as $disp => $value )
    {
        $curValue = explode(' | ', $moneyDeck[$disp]);
        $curName = explode(', ', $settings->getValue( 'tcg_currency' ));
        $arrayCur = array();
        foreach( $curValue as $key => $value )
        {
            $tn = substr_replace($curName[$key],"",-4);
            if( $curValue[$key] > 1 )
            {
                $var = substr($tn, -1);
                if( $var == "y" )
                {
                    $tn = substr_replace($tn,"ies",-1);
                }
                else if( $var == "o" )
                {
                    $tn = substr_replace($tn,"oes",-1);
                }
                else
                {
                    $tn = $tn.'s';
                }
            }

            else
            {
                $tn = $tn;
            }

            if( $curValue[$key] == 0 ) {}
            else
            {
                $arrayCur[] = $curValue[$key].' '.$tn.', ';
            }
        }
        $arrayCur = implode(" ", $arrayCur);
        $arrayCur = substr_replace($arrayCur,"",-2);

        // Add tr lines for each deck mastery type
        if( $disp == 0 ) { $mast = 'Regular'; }
        elseif( $disp == 1 ) { $mast = 'Special'; }
        elseif( $disp == 2 ) { $mast = 'Rare'; }

        echo '<tr>
            <td align="center">'.$mast.' Decks</td>
            <td align="center">'.$choiceDeck[$disp].' choice, '.$randomDeck[$disp].' random, '.$arrayCur.'</td>
        </tr>';
    }

    echo '</tbody>
</table>';
```